# What is the best practice for returning results gathered from Observables in an Observable?

Tags: java, java-7, rx-java

I'm using RxJava for my project and I am puzzled a bit with this piece of code:

```
    @Override
    public Observable<Hexagon<T>> getHexagons() {
        return Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Hexagon<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Hexagon<T>> subscriber) {
                hexagonDataStorage.getCoordinates().subscribe(new Subscriber<CubeCoordinate>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
                        System.err.println(String.format("Cannot get Hexagons: <%s>", throwable.getMessage()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(final CubeCoordinate cubeCoordinate) {
                        subscriber.onNext(new HexagonImpl<>(gridData, cubeCoordinate, hexagonDataStorage));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

What I'm basically trying to do here is to

- get all the `CubeCoordinate` objects by calling the `getCoordinates` method which in fact returns an `Observable`
- transform the `CubeCoordinate` objects into `Hexagon` objects and return the result as a new `Observable`.

This example is working but it is really tiring on my eyes and also smells. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Also is there an implementation of `Subscriber` which only makes me override `onCompleted` and `onNext`? `onError` is not needed in my case. I checked the source code but there is a gazillion of implementations and I can't differentiate based on my criteria.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question - the operator you are looking for is [`map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html):

```
public Observable<Hexagon<T>> getHexagons() {
    return hexagonDataStorage.getCoordinates()
            .map(cubeCoordinate -> new HexagonImpl<>(gridData, cubeCoordinate, hexagonDataStorage))
}
```

It does exactly what you want - it transforms each item by applying a function.

---

To answer your second question - I highly suggest you always override `onError`, otherwise, if the RxJava stream encounters an exception, it will throw [`OnErrorNotImplementedException`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/exceptions/OnErrorNotImplementedException.html). You can make an abstract class that extends `Subscriber` and implement `onError` there and leave the other two methods abstract.

Comment: I see. I'm using java 7 here so I don't have lambdas but I will look into this, thanks!